# step counter, how do I add steps to the dashboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

I closed the step counter by accident and now I can only see floors and miles. I cannot find the page where I can re-open the step counter to add to dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

open health app - tap **Health Data** at the bottom, search for **steps** in the top search field - tap **Show on Dashboard**